# python pandas date_range when importing with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file with some data in the following format:

```
1.69511909,  0.57561167,  0.31437427,  0.35458831,  0.15841189, 0.28239582, -0.18180907,  1.34761404, -1.5059083,  1.29246638
-1.66764664,  0.1488095,  1.03832221, -0.35229205,  1.35705861, -1.56747104, -0.36783851, -0.57636948,  0.9854391,  1.63031066
0.87763775,  0.60757153,  0.64908314, -0.68357724,  0.33499838, -0.08557089,  1.71855596, -0.61235066, -0.32520105,  1.54162629
```

Every line corresponds to a specific day, and every record in a line corresponds to a specific hour in that day.

Is there is a convenient way of importing the data with `read_csv` such that everything would be correctly indexed, i.e. the importing function would discriminate different days (lines), and hours within days (separate records in lines).

Comment: Is it *exactly* like this, i.e. it has newlines between every row? Or is this an issue with the renderer? How do you know which lines correspond to which days and which columns correspond to which hour?

Comment: The .csv file doesn't have newlines. I had problem properly formatting the text when writing the original post.

Comment: Ah ok, if you don't mind I'll go in and change it for you (the easiest way is to just paste the text and use Ctrl+K (or highlight and use the `{}` button).

Comment: and the what about the other part, how do you know the dates/hours from this table?

Comment: i just now, it starts on '1/1/2010 07:00:00' and continues '+1 day every line', and '+1 hour every record in the line'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just read in the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',\s+', header=None)
```

Then set the index to be the dates and the columns to be the hours*

```
df.index = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', freq='D', periods=len(df))
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Hour
df.columns = [Hour(7+t) for t in df.columns]

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
            <7 Hours>  <8 Hours>  <9 Hours>  <10 Hours>  <11 Hours>   <12 Hours>  <13 Hours>  <14 Hours>  <15 Hours>  <16 Hours>
2012-01-01   1.695119   0.575612   0.314374    0.354588    0.158412   0.282396   -0.181809    1.347614   -1.505908    1.292466
2012-01-02  -1.667647   0.148810   1.038322   -0.352292    1.357059  -1.567471   -0.367839   -0.576369    0.985439    1.630311
2012-01-03   0.877638   0.607572   0.649083   -0.683577    0.334998  -0.085571    1.718556   -0.612351   -0.325201    1.541626
```

Then stack it and add the Date and the Hour levels of the MultiIndex:

```
s = df.stack()
s.index = [x[0]+x[1] for x in s.index]

In [8]: s
Out[8]:
2012-01-01 07:00:00    1.695119
2012-01-01 08:00:00    0.575612
2012-01-01 09:00:00    0.314374
2012-01-01 10:00:00    0.354588
2012-01-01 11:00:00    0.158412
2012-01-01 12:00:00    0.282396
2012-01-01 13:00:00   -0.181809
2012-01-01 14:00:00    1.347614
2012-01-01 15:00:00   -1.505908
2012-01-01 16:00:00    1.292466
2012-01-02 07:00:00   -1.667647
2012-01-02 08:00:00    0.148810
...
```

* *You can use different offsets, [see here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects), e.g. `Minute`, `Second`.*

Comment: yours is probably more robust to an error like only 23 values in a single line (mine would make it off by 1), but as I warned....user is responsible for have a clean file when no labels are supplied; actually a thought, name your method with a supplied ``names=`` argument would be good?

Comment: @Jeff you've lost me... :)

Comment: oh...you could pass ``names=[ Hour(7+t) for t in range(24) ]`` in the read_csv

Comment: @AndyHayden, you are the bomb! :) That was exactly what I needed, fantastic! Thank you. Could I please ask two more questions about your solution? Just to understand things. What does the sep syntax after the comma sign mean, i.e., sep=',\s+'? And second, how could I modify your code in the 'df.columns = ...' line, if the time delta between the records in the same line was different, say, e.g. 15 minutes, or 30 seconds (I have such files as well)? Thank you again :-)

Comment: the sep part is a regex what to use to seperate columns, `',\s+'` says a comma and then some number of spaces. If the timedelta is different you can use `from pandas.tseries.offsets import Minute, Second` (see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects))

Comment: Is there any slightest chance that there is something wrong with the code above? I'm following everything exactly just now, and in Out[5] I can't get multiple 'names' of columns, I'm just getting one, i.e., <7 Hours>. @AndyHayden

Comment: Did you include `header=None` in your `read_csv`? What is `df.columns` after `read_csv`? (I've just rechecked and it works with your example csv.)

Comment: I rechecked everything twice before replying now, but it's really as I had said. `header = None` is definitely there, `df.columns` after `read_csv` is `Int64Index([0], dtype=int64)`

Comment: @Jeff That's probably very silly but I'm trying to implement your suggestion about passing `names=[ Hour(7+t) for t in range(24) ]` in `read_csv` but I'm getting error message `ValueError: Expected 24 fields in line 1, saw 1`. Any clue why?

Comment: try doing it as a string (which negates the ability to add later)....but lets see: ``names=[ str(5+t) for t in range(24) ]``, just a guess though....

Comment: @AndyHayden, please have a look, if you'd find time.

Comment: OK, it is solved. I don't understand why but when I replaced sep=',\s+' with sep=',', everything started to work... Cheers guys!

Comment: (Sorry was away) Glad you got it fixed! That'll be because there are no spaces in your csv? :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. Note that I couldn't copy your string for some reason, so my dataset is cutoff....

Read in the string (it reads as a dataframe because mine had newlines in it)....but need to coerce to a Series.

```
In [23]: s = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data)).values

In [24]: s
Out[24]: 
array([[-1.66764664,  0.1488095 ,  1.03832221, -0.35229205,  1.35705861,
        -1.56747104, -0.36783851, -0.57636948,  0.9854391 ,  1.63031066],
       [ 0.87763775,  0.60757153,  0.64908314, -0.68357724,  0.33499838,
        -0.08557089,  1.71855596,         nan,         nan,         nan]])

In [25]: s = Series(pd.read_csv(StringIO(data)).values.ravel())

In [26]: s
Out[26]: 
0    -1.667647
1     0.148810
2     1.038322
3    -0.352292
4     1.357059
5    -1.567471
6    -0.367839
7    -0.576369
8     0.985439
9     1.630311
10    0.877638
11    0.607572
12    0.649083
13   -0.683577
14    0.334998
15   -0.085571
16    1.718556
17         NaN
18         NaN
19         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Just set the index directly....Note that you are solely responsible for alignment, this is VERY
easy to be say off by 1

```
In [27]: s.index = pd.date_range('20130101',freq='H',periods=len(s))

In [28]: s
Out[28]: 
2013-01-01 00:00:00   -1.667647
2013-01-01 01:00:00    0.148810
2013-01-01 02:00:00    1.038322
2013-01-01 03:00:00   -0.352292
2013-01-01 04:00:00    1.357059
2013-01-01 05:00:00   -1.567471
2013-01-01 06:00:00   -0.367839
2013-01-01 07:00:00   -0.576369
2013-01-01 08:00:00    0.985439
2013-01-01 09:00:00    1.630311
2013-01-01 10:00:00    0.877638
2013-01-01 11:00:00    0.607572
2013-01-01 12:00:00    0.649083
2013-01-01 13:00:00   -0.683577
2013-01-01 14:00:00    0.334998
2013-01-01 15:00:00   -0.085571
2013-01-01 16:00:00    1.718556
2013-01-01 17:00:00         NaN
2013-01-01 18:00:00         NaN
2013-01-01 19:00:00         NaN
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```